# Proving Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem using Egorov theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I'm trying to prove Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) by using Egorov's theorem. And so far, I know how to do it when the functions are defined in finite measure set in real. Is it possible to also prove DCT using Egorov when the functions are defined in a set in reals where the set isn't a finite measure?

Comment: The DCT is easier to prove than Egorov's theorem though, and lives in a significantly more general setting